# Nested checbox in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote a nested checkbox as follows

> state and function

```
const [selectedRow, setSelectedRow] = useState([]);
const [selectedPropertyOfRow, setSelectedPropertyOfRow] = useState([]);
const isSelectedRow = (name) => selectedRow.indexOf(name) !== -1; // row is check?
const isSelectedPropertyInRow = (name) => selectedPropertyOfRow.indexOf(name) !== -1; // children of row is check?

// when click on Children of the row this function selected/unselect one children
const handleCheckedPropertyInRow = (event, prpId, item) => {
  let newSelectedRow = [...selectedRow];
  const selectedIndexRow = newSelectedRow.indexOf(item.host.id);
  let newSelected = [...selectedPropertyOfRow];
  const selectedIndex = newSelected.indexOf(prpId);

  if (selectedIndex !== -1) {
    newSelected.splice(selectedIndex, 1);
  } else if (selectedIndex === -1) {
    newSelected.push(prpId);
    if (selectedIndexRow === -1) {
      newSelectedRow.push(item.host.id);
    }
  }
  setSelectedPropertyOfRow(newSelected);
  setSelectedRow(newSelectedRow);
};

//  when click on row checkbox this function selected/unselect row and ALL children
const handleSelectAllPropertyInRow = (event, item) => {
  let newSelectedRow = [...selectedRow];
  const selectedIndex = newSelectedRow.indexOf(item.host.id);
  if (selectedIndex !== -1) {
    newSelectedRow.splice(selectedIndex, 1);
  } else if (selectedIndex === -1) {
    newSelectedRow.push(item.host.id);
  }
  setSelectedRow(newSelectedRow);

  if (event.target.checked) {
    const newSelectedPropertyOfRow = item.properties.map((pr) => pr.id);
    setSelectedPropertyOfRow((prevState) => [
      ...prevState,
      ...newSelectedPropertyOfRow,
    ]);
    return;
  }
  let newSelected = [...selectedPropertyOfRow];
  const newSelectedPropertyOfRow = item.properties.map((pr) => pr.id);
  for (let elm of newSelectedPropertyOfRow) {
    const selectedIndex = newSelected.indexOf(elm);
    if (selectedIndex !== -1) {
      newSelected.splice(selectedIndex, 1);
    }
  }
  setSelectedPropertyOfRow(newSelected);
};

// when click on root checkbox this function selected/unselect all checkbox
const handleSelectAllClick = (event) => {
  if (event.target.checked) {
    const newSelectedRow = items.map((item) => item?.host.id);
    const newSelectedPropertyOfRow = items
      .map((item) => item.properties.map((pr) => pr.id))
      .flat();
    setSelectedRow(newSelectedRow);
    setSelectedPropertyOfRow(newSelectedPropertyOfRow);
    return;
  }
  setSelectedRow([]);
  setSelectedPropertyOfRow([]);
};
```

> Data from api

```
const items = [
  {
    host: { id: 8, host_name: "Aman Sharma", ...otherInfo }, // render in row info
    properties: [ // children of each row
      {
        id: 700,
        host_owner_id: 8,
        ...otherInfo,
      },
      {
        id: 701,
        host_owner_id: 8,
        ...otherInfo,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    host: { id: 12, host_name: "Lawrence Adjei", ...otherInfo },
    properties: [
      {
        id: 565,
        host_owner_id: 12,
        ...otherInfo,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

> JSX code

```
// root checkbox
  <PrimaryCheckbox
    indeterminate={selectedRow.length > 0 && selectedRow.length < items.length}
    checked={items.length > 0 && selectedRow.length === items.length}
    onChange={handleSelectAllClick}
  />
  // end root checkbox


<div className="row">
  <div className="col-12">
    {items.map((item, index) => {
      const isItemSelected = isSelectedRow(item?.host.id);
      return (
        <React.Fragment key={item.host.id}>
          <div className={classes.hostRow}>
            <div className="checkbox d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
              {/* ... other stuff ...*/}

              {/* each row checkbox */}
              <PrimaryCheckbox
                onClick={(event) => handleSelectAllPropertyInRow(event, item)}
                checked={isItemSelected}
              />
              {/*end each row checkbox */}

              {/* ... other stuff ...*/}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            {item.properties.map((property) => {
              const isItemSelected = isSelectedPropertyInRow(property.id);
              return (
                <CardItem
                  key={property.id}
                  property={property}
                  checkboxComponent={
                    // each children of row checkbox
                    <PrimaryCheckbox
                      onClick={(event) =>
                        handleCheckedPropertyInRow(event, property.id, item)
                      }
                      checked={isItemSelected}
                    />
                    // end each children of row checkbox
                  }
                  isItemSelected={isItemSelected}
                />
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    })}
  </div>
</div>;
```

> Output view

[image]

> My problem (important)

**I want to uncheck the father of children when uncheck all children of row**,  (As you can see in the picture children is uncheck but row is check)

> What is your experience?

how can write better nested checkbox?

What is the best practice for better writing in this case?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a state in top level parents component ax fallowing:

```
const [checkAll, setChekAll] = useState(false);
```

and pass it as props to nested item and children and when it has change you can change local check value with this:

```
useEffect(() => { setLocalCheckValue(checkAll) }, [checkAll]);
```

whwn you do this all checkboxes sync with checkAll Value